# SQL Server : Weekly update statistics job

Tags: sql-server

On a SQL server, why do we need a weekly update stats job (with full scan) when we have AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS=ON for all databases?

Doesn't this option update statistics all the time?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, it depends on the table size and the number of rows being updated whether status updates will be triggered; an occasional rebuild is a good idea. [Some info on the algorithm for auto updates](http://blogs.technet.com/rob/archive/2008/05/16/sql-server-statistics.aspx)

Comment: it depends on the table size and the number of rows being updated ?
can you please give me an example?

Comment: See link posted above. Stats get updated when a threshold is crossed, not after every update; it's not uncommon to not use auto_update so updates don't happen at random intervals (they're not random, but tell that to the user that just updated a record that triggered the update, causing a blip in performance while stats get updated). If you turn off auto_update, you MUST do occasional rebuilds.

Comment: Thansk a lot for this article